# Left toggle menu , like in facebook

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I believe everyone would have seen, facebook mobile app. Also in many flat UI patterns website.

I would like to make one such Left menu.

THis is what I did now.

1. Hide the menu initially (`display:none`)
2. On click of the menu button. Show the left menu (`toogle`), and increase the left margin on main content using javascript (`style,maregin-left:100px;`)

This is working fine, but  I just want to know, is this the best practice, and will this responsive?

Comment: We can help you much more if you show us some of your code but at least from what you described, this is very typical for responsive design (hiding things, changing margins dynamically with javascript, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you re doing is good but for  best practice i will use the css3 transform  with translate  some thing like this

```
.menu{ -webkit-transform:translateX(-200px)
```

from there you can use the toggleClass("active") from jquery

```
.menu.active{-webkit-transfrom:translateX(0)}
```

hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

The design pattern is known as 'off canvas' layout.

Depending on the nature of the content you might not want to have it hidden on larger screen, depends on your requirements.

There is a good example of what I mean here: http://jasonweaver.name/lab/offcanvas/

Where the navigation is visible on full screen and hidden on smaller mobile viewports.

Comment: +1 for the Pattern name.  Is there a correct way to implement?

Comment: Not a correct way as such just drawbacks to the pattern.

If it's a navigation menu and it's hidden by default (as opposed to on page load) it may be inaccessible to users on older technology.

Think *progressive enhancement*

http://stephanierieger.com/a-plea-for-progressive-enhancement/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a perfectly fine approach and it should behave responsively since it's only taking up 100px of width. If it was a full screen horizontal drop-down menu, then you would have to make sure its contents are responsive, but a 100px wide vertical menu will be fine on just about any resolution (especially if the user can choose to toggle it open or closed).